# Disable the css style on the specific html item

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I have css style:

```
#topmenu a:hover {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 8px 20px 7px 12px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #48516D;
}
```

And then, I have a topmenu div with some `<a>` inside. I would like to disable the hover style on one of the  elements, for example on this one:

```
<div id="topmenu">
    <a href="/"><img width="85" src="/bundles/merrinmain/images/design/homepage.png"></a>
```

How can I do this? Should I set the `style=""` to something else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have other elements in this div, any other anchor tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "reset" the styles, so to speak, on a specific element directly, but you could give it a class that is styled the same as the non-hovered links.

```
#topmenu a, /* apply to non-hovered links */
#topmenu a.noHover:hover { /* and apply to .noHover even when hovered */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 8px 20px 7px 12px;
        color: fuchsia; /* yay */
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #48516D;
}
#topmenu a:hover {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 8px 20px 7px 12px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: underline;
        background-color: #48516D;
}
```

This way only links without the "noHover" class will have the hover effects applied. Note that you need to specify **all** the relevant properties that change (`color`, `text-decoration` etc.) in the first rule (for normal links and `.noHover`) in order to override the second `:hover` rule's properties.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/N8txa/

Answer (score 1):

Apply another class to that item overwriting the inherited hover implementation

like css

```
a.mylink:hover {
        margin: 0;
        //some other styles
}
```

html

```
 <a href="/" class="mylink">
```